# how to have maven and intellij idea generate resources as part of build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, resources

In my java-SWT project I have a bunch of icons in `.svg` format, but I do not know how to create SWT images out of `.svg` resources, so I convert them to `.png` first, using ImageMagick.  The `.svg` files continue to be the "source" images: when I want to edit an icon, I always edit the `.svg` file, not the `.png` file.

<sup>(If you can tell me how to create SWT images from `.svg` resources I would be grateful, but that's not the actual question.)</sup>

Right now I am initiating the svg-to-png conversion manually: each time I change one of the `.svg` files, I run a shell script which repeatedly invokes ImageMagick to convert them all to `.png` and store them in the right resources folder, and then later the build step copies them from that folder to the output folder where the running application can find them.

I would like to know two things:

1. How to automate the svg-to-png conversion as part of the maven build, so that the full conversion happens when I do `mvn clean install`, and so that only the `.svg` files that have actually changed get converted when I do `mvn install` (without `clean`.)
2. How to convince IntelliJ IDEA to do the same. (Because for the most part, I like to be able to just hit "Build-And-Run" in IDEA without bothering with maven.)

I do not mind at all if the generated `.png` files go directly to the resources directory in the output folder tree of the project instead of the resources directory under the source folder tree.  That would actually save the "copying resources" step, so it would be good.

So, this question is essentially about custom compilation: the `.svg` files can be thought of as source files, the `.png` files can be thought of as binary output files, and ImageMagick can be thought of as the compiler.  The question can be restated as how to use a) maven and b) intelliJ IDEA to do a "make" for a custom compiler that these tools have no knowledge of by default.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a pom module, a sub-project that produces a jar with .png resources, generated from the .svg files.(`src/main/svg/...` maybe.)
- Then add a dependency to that library jar in your using jar.
- Use a ClassLoader to fetch the resources.

This is a bit needlessly circuitous, but forms a clear production line.

---

One option would be the maven [**exec**](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin.

A totally other approach would be to use the java **batik** library for svg.

Comment: I think I understand what you are getting at, but it is still entirely unclear to me how to accomplish it.  So, you are saying that my project will depend on some resources-jar project, and since the .svg files will be in the source tree of the resources-jar project, changing an .svg file will cause a rebuild of that project.  Fine.  But still, how do I convert .svg to .png-in-a-jar as part of building the resources-jar project?